# I have problems using bootstrap

Tags: reactjs

```
./src/components/todos-list.component.js
  Line 49:  'Dropdown' is not defined     react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 49:  'ButtonGroup' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 50:  'Button' is not defined       react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 52:  'Dropdown' is not defined     react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 53:  'Dropdown' is not defined     react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 54:  'Dropdown' is not defined     react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 55:  'Dropdown' is not defined     react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 56:  'Dropdown' is not defined     react/jsx-no-undef
```

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: you are using bootstrap or ReactBootstrap?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code. Best guess at this point is you didn't import them in the component trying to use them.